# Redundance in statement of second morphism theorem

Tags: group-theory

The standard statement of the Second Morphism Theorem found in my textbook and Wikipedia is as follows:

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ be any subgroup of $G$.

$HN = \{hn | h \in H, n \in N\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

$H \cap N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$

$H / (H \cap N) \cong HN / N$

Isn't the third part redundant?  In particular, isn't $HN / N$ just $H/N$?  That is, cosets in $HN/N$ are given by $hnN$.  But by the closure of $N$, a group, this is equal to $hN$.  Also, since $N$ is a normal subgroup, (since we are taking the quotient?) right cosets should equal left cosets, so we don't have to look at $nHN$.

Perhaps I've gone wrong somewhere, but if not, I'd like some insight on why this is stated "redundantly" -- is it just convention?

Comment: How do you know that $N$ is a ***normal subgroup of $H$***?

Comment: Ah, you're right -- I suppose you don't, thanks for pointing that out. But the much weaker statement that this intuition does demonstrate is that in the case where N is a normal subgroup of H, HN/N = H/N, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider a specific example: Take $G = D_4 = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,y,xy,x^2y,x^3y\}$ and set $H = \{1,y\}$ and $N = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. Being an index $2$ subgroup of $G$, $N$ is normal in $G$. But now you ***can't even form*** $H/N$ because $N$ is ***not even contained*** in $H$.

If $N$ is ***a normal subgroup of $G$*** that is ***contained in $H$*** then the second isomorphism theorem says that $H \cap N = N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. Then indeed
$$H/(H \cap N) = H/N \cong HN/N.$$

Comment: Thank you -- this example helps makes things concrete where I went wrong.

Comment: @WeierstrassSauce I have added something to my answer, in response to your comment above to your question.